In Spring(not boot), Websocket endpoint error
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
...
  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry
    .addEndpoint("/websocket")
    .setAllowedOrigins("*")
    .addInterceptors(new HttpHandshakeInterceptor())
    .withSockJS();
  }
...
}

It is my Spring Porject websocket Config.
And now, I try to connect from client.
const socket = new SockJS('http://{IP:PORT}/websocket'); // sucess
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://{IP:PORT}/websocket'); // fail
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://{IP:PORT}/websocket/websocket'); // success

I need to connect by second way(acually it is android), but I can't access by that path/websocket.
How should I modify my code?
+
spring-websocket : 4.3.25.RELEASE
